# Can I run just one wire to the sub-panel via schedule 40 separate from the others?

Tags: subpanel, grounding-and-bonding

I have a 25 year old recalled sub panel, three wire, converting to new Eaton 100A. Want to add a wire to meet code

Is it allowed by code to run just one wire to the sub panel via schedule 40 to the panel separate from the other three?  The original wires are in the ceiling over living space (mess to access.) 2 AWG.

In planning I wanted to run a hot, but as it turns out I can't make the existing neutral in main reach the neutral bus.  (I suppose since it should be bonded I could lug in to ground.)  But now I'm planning to run the black wire as neutral (mark with white on both ends) and keep the neutral as the second black as it would be in a 4 wire (mark it red).  How much trouble am I in?

Comment: Very confusing. **What is the goal of adding a 4th wire?** Or to put it another way, what is the function that is missing that a 4th wire will take care of? If the 4th wire is a **ground** then under limited circumstances you can retrofit a ground via a different path. But all hot & neutral wires must be together (same cable or same conduit). If part of the problem is a wire that won't quite reach then you can splice it (with a proper wire nut, etc.) inside the panel box or if it is a little shorter than that, put in a proper box outside the panel and splice it there.

Comment: Thanks, Manassehkatz, my limitations are: There is a 100A breaker mounted there, so have to get that.  Don't want to bond neutral to ground.  Only way I know of us to use 4 wire system to meet code/requirements.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Are the existing wires running in a conduit? Or are they multi-conductor cable?

Comment: Hey, Harper, they are up in a finished ceiling someplace.  I will have to see if they are wrapped - I believe so.

Comment: So it sounds like (please confirm): Old recalled subpanel that is being replaced has 2 hots + neutral connecting it to the main panel, and you are trying to, as code requires, add a ground wire for the new subpanel. If so, if the existing wires are in metal conduit then you *may* be able to use that as a ground path. Depends on what you have and what Harper tells you to do.

Comment: Yes, Manassehkatz, that's a good summary.  I'll check on the existing three wire past ceiling entry to see if it is in conduit.  There is a bare copper ground among the three so I think it is jacketed.  I doubt there is a conduit but will verify.  But since i have a bare one, not sure if I can use the new 2 AWG as ground?

Comment: Can you post photos of where the wires enter from the cable into the subpanel?

Comment: Update: Manassehkatz I mis-spoke...not really two hots plus neutral.  Really hot, neutral and ground in the exisitng 3-wire bundle.  ThreePhaseEel, I'll go and get a shot now.  Back in a few.  Thanks, guys!

Comment: https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0TJu8EH6JKhqf2 for photos of the current state.  New panel back and front.  Shots of the outside main also.

Comment: How fat of a conduit can you run down the new route?

Comment: Basically unlimited space.  It's a closed off hallway next to the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Run a new feeder in metal conduit

If you're going to run a conduit from the main panel to the subpanel, I would simply run a 2" EMT and pull an entirely new 100A feeder (1AWG Al hot/hot/neutral with the EMT for a ground) through it in your situation.  This is because the existing feeder SE(?) cable seems to have been improperly installed to begin with (its jacket does not extend down into the strain-relief clamp on the cable entrance), and as a result should not be relied upon for continued service.

While you are at it, you should re-terminate the existing NM cables into junction boxes above the panel, then bring the circuits down from those boxes using NM "jumbo pigtails" into the panel that are properly strain-relieved.  This because the original installer screwed up the strain relief on the branch-circuit NM cables going out of the subpanel, as well.

Comment: @chicken_neck -- we express our thanks around here by upvoting and accepting answers :)